# How to make an extra button in ListPreference in java, android

Tags: java, android, button, preferences, listpreference

I wanna make a second button near the "Cancel" button in my ListPreference and implement my onClickListener on it, how should I do it? Thanks.

my preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<ListPreference
    android:dialogTitle="@string/LangDialogTitle"
    android:entries="@array/entries_lang"
    android:entryValues="@array/entryvalues_lang"
    android:key="lang"
    android:summary="@string/LangSummary"
    android:title="@string/LangTitle" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: which 'Cancel' button?

Comment: A standard "Cancel" button in ListPreference

Comment: check this link: http://blog.isys-labs.com/creating-a-custom-listpreference/

Comment: Thanks, found a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520021/using-listpreference-and-getting-the-key-works-but-no-ok-button

Comment: Look into this [Custom List Preference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4557852/3326331)